# Solving a big matrix DE system using NDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I know there are similar questions, but I was unable to understand the solution for my case in any of them.

I have the following:

```
Commutator[a_,b_] := a.b - b.a;

initialstate = {0,1,0};
pin = KroneckerProduct[Conjugate[initialstate],initialstate];

pI = NDSolveValue[{
p'[t] == - Commutator[p[t].F1[t], L[t]] + Commutator[ConjugateTranspose[F1[t]].p[t], ConjugateTranspose[L[t]]]
- Commutator[p[t].F2[t], ConjugateTranspose[L[t]]] + Commutator[ConjugateTranspose[F2[t]].p[t], L[t]],
p[0] == pin
},
p,{t,0,1}]
```

It might be relevant to say that F1(t) and F2(t) are both numerical 3x3 functions and L(t) is a big analytic 3x3 function.

I have seen in other posts that the sum will act before the dot operators causing Mathematica to misinterpret what I am trying to calculate. It indeed returns me an error if I try to execute it, so what the correct syntax for this problem is? Where I have dot operators not only in the DE system but also inside the Commutator function.

I would really appreciate it if, besides the solution, you could provide me an explanation of what is happening.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the definitions of F1, F2 and L. When I use random matrix functions for these functions, NDSolveValue returns with no errors.

Comment: Search the MMA help for "Operator Input Forms". Then under "Operator Precedence" all operators are listed from high to low precedence. You will see that Dot has higher precedence than Plus. An example: {1, 1}.{2, 2} + {3, 3} is evaluated like:( {1, 1}.{2, 2})+ {3, 3} Therefore, what you claim is doubtful. Could you give an example?